# DataTable.RowFilter using List results?

Tags: linq, datagridview, ado.net, datatable

I need to keep the original DataTable and filter it based on list values. I've tried to hide rows that don't match up to the list but it doesn't work instantly. I don't want to copy the list to another dataTable and bind my dataGridView to is cause i have too much tied up to the original DataTable. Filtering only works for a few conditions but the list is holds only the values that are needed. Is there a LINQ solution to this? C# only please. This is how I got my list. There is another dataGridView that holds primary key for the datatable that I need to filter. It's key is held in a comboBox.

```
DataTable MainTable = MainDataSet.Tables["MyTable"];

DataTable lookupTable = lookupDataSet.Tables["MyLookupTable"];

var List = (from x in lookupTable.AsEnumerable()
            where x.Field<string>("kAutoInc") == comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()
            select x.Field<int>("Pct")).ToList();

var a = MainTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r =>
                  List .Any(id => id == r.Field<int>("Pct")));
```

This gives me values of int 30, 40, 50, 60...

The DataGridView has a matching column "Pct" that I need to filter rows that only contain these values. I know it seems easy but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please use DataView instead.

```
dataview dv=new dataview(datatable);  
dv.filter=string.format("column1={0}","value1");
```

Like that.